# How Can I make a Nivo Slider transition with text below-NOT CAPTION?

Tags: slider, transition, caption, nivo-slider

OK, So I am working on this Nivo Slider for a website I am doing for my school... I am wondering if it is possible to actually get the Nivo Slider to transition with text below. Not necessarily a caption but like when the Nivo goes to a new image the text below will go to another bit of text. I have the Nivo working in all browsers but I was curious if anyone knew if this was even possible. I tryed putting large text in a caption but It just made the caption go all over the Nivo instead of down below the image like I want..

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

You can place text below the gallery using the caption option and just display it below using CSS.

Simply go in to the `nivo-slider.css` file and change the `position` of the `nivo-caption` class to `relative`.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible, with simple css modification you can display the captions under the slider and they'll fade at the same time as the images.

Kind regards